# launchMode() в Android

Tags: android, activity, backstack

Есть MainActivity. Способа ее запуска два: через иконку приложения и при открытии файла с расширением *.ext . По умолчанию все работает хорошо, кроме того, что если activity уже создано и мы его открываем с помощью файла с расширением *.ext то создается еще один экземпляр MainActivity и ложится на верх стека, а нужно, чтобы оно работало как singleTask(то есть открывало уже имеющееся Activity и убивало все Activity сверху). Но если поставить для MainActivity launchMode = "singleTask", то появляется другая проблема: если Activity уже существует и поверх него открыта другая Activity, то при запуске с иконки приложения он убивает все Activity выше MainActivity, а мне надо, чтобы через иконку он работал как launchMode="standart". То есть мне надо, чтобы при запуске приложения через иконку был эффект launchMode = "standart", а при запуске через файл с расширением *.ext был эффект launchMode = "singleTask". Буду очень благодарен за любые идеи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716737/whats-the-best-way-to-clear-an-existing-task-to-top-without-changing-launchmode. Если вкратце, то нужно создать еще один Activity, который будет работать с фильтрами и в нем управлять флагами intentа.